# Practical difference between Consumable and Non-Renewable subscription

Tags: cocoa, in-app-purchase

I've been experimenting with the In-App purchases to see what's more suitable for my product.

There are clear differences between Consumable/Non-Consumable and Auto renewable subscriptions

But when it comes to Non-renewable, the only difference I see is a semantic one. From Apple docs: "Non-renewing subscriptions and consumable products are not automatically restored by Store Kit. Non-renewing subscriptions must be restorable, however."

So, my question as stated, is there any real difference (for me as a developer) between those two? (that I can benefit from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually not clear at all. The best resource I can guide you to is Session 308 from WWDC 2012.

They don't explicitly explain the difference but near the end you can see things like the popup names and email formats are different. Generally subscriptions seem to be handled more like subscriptions for customers.

For you as a developer, yes there are differences. Mainly to do with how the transaction receipt is handled (again in the WWDC session).